# Data encoding for machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, data-science, prediction

[dataset image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/658mY.png)  I have transportation dataset which contains 6 categorical variables(i.e sender,reciver,truckername,fromcity,tocity,vehicletype) and one continuous variable(i.e weight).i want to predict sale(which is continuous variable). i have 13000 records in dataset.

I have already tried one hot encoding but there are more than 300 category in each variable that means (300*6 = 1800 variables).so how can
encode the columns or is there any other solution to this?

Here you can see sample dataset:

Comment: you need to ask yourself which variables are relevant to sales price. For example, do the names of the sender/receiver actually matter?

Comment: we could apply the same logic to truckername, but I'm assuming that's the name of the company so that might actually be related.

Comment: sender is the initial owner of the goods, while the receiver may simply be an agent, not actually taking ownership of the goods.and trucker is a company name which provides a truck to ship that goods.receiver company/customer/agent can be same as sender or it can be different company/customer/agent

Comment: why would you one hot encode your input data? simply count from 0 to n for n possible classes for each variable

Answer (score 0):

Sale is you target variable and rest are independent variables. You can use Logistic regression (There are different types of them) to predict the sale with respect to other variables. You need to dig bit deeper into regression model suitable to your need.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do the below things :

1 - You need to find the correlation and decide which variables are needed. So that you can remove the variables like name. Because they might not contribute significantly to the results. Encode only the variables that are significantly important.

2 - Try to create new variables by grouping the values, like vehicle type / cities and reduce the unique values and find whether its important . So that you can have the new values instead of old columns.

3 - Try to use different encoding based on the values in the columns, like Ordinal Encoding. Which might help you to reduce the column count.

Comment: i have tried label encoding but there is no order in variables..

Comment: How many unique values are there in Sender, Receiver and Trucker Name ? You can easily group them by numbering the unique values . If there are 300 unique values, you can easily replace them with 300 numbers without encoding which should not create any trouble to the model.

Answer (score 0):

There is three option for label encoding I learned.

**Drop columns with categorical data**
Start with this then if there's not many categorical variable.

**Label encoding**
This second possibility will tranform your values to numeric for example: ['tuesday','most','three'] to [1,2,3]. But here if you've have already splited your data to train and test pleas check if your unique values in test data and train data are not the same one.

```
# Apply label encoder 
encoderlab =  LabelEncoder()
for col in cols:
    label_X_train[col] = encoderlab.fit_transform(label_X_train[col])
    label_X_valid[col] = encoderlab.transform(label_X_valid[col])
```

**One-hot encoding**
This third possibility, for each column with categorical data check the number of unique values in the column. if there's many unique valuesgreater than 10 it's better to **label encode them** and the others with less than 10 unique values one hot encode them.

```
oh_encod = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse=False)
OH_X_train = pd.DataFrame(oh_encod.fit_transform(X_train[low_cardinality_cols]))
OH_X_valid = pd.DataFrame(oh_encod.transform(X_valid[low_cardinality_cols]))
```

Learn more in Kaggle [handling-categorical-variables](https://www.kaggle.com/abdoulsn/house-price-handling-categorical-variables)(details on exercises)  or [categorical-variables](https://www.kaggle.com/alexisbcook/categorical-variables)